# Upgrading Magento 1.2.0.3 to 1.6.1.0

Tags: magento

A client has an old version of Magento (1.2.0.3).  Can I upgrade directly to (1.6.1.0) or do I have to go through a progressive series of upgrades to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I think it's better to do progressive updates. It's also better to keep up with new versions and don't let clients fall behind too much. Consider offering them a maintenance contract for a monthly fee or a fee per upgrade.

The biggest changes are between version 1.3 and 1.4 where the Magento team has done a fairly large overhaul of all templates by optimizing the HTML and renaming CSS class names. So it will also depends on how much customization has been done to the site's theme. I've just completed a 1.3.x upgrade to 1.4.2 which took be about 100 hours. This is long for such an upgrade but I've also done a lot of clean up work as the 1.3.x version was not very well built (by another web agency).
The website is now much more upgrade proof and upgrading to 1.5.x and 1.6.x is now a fairly straight forward job taking probably just a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

Go for progressive and turn off any modifications
 and use default template. backup each upgrade step